# Are there implicit parentheses around fractions?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I was just looking at a simple math question that came across my social media feed and noticed something I must have always ignored in the past.

In this equation $x = 3 \div \frac{1}{3}$ there seems to be an implicit set of parentheses around $\frac{1}{3}$ which yields a result of $x= 9$.

This seems strange to me because I look at $\frac{1}{3} = 1 \div 3$ and wonder why we can't rewrite it as $x = 3 \div \frac{1}{3} = 3 \div 1 \div 3 = 1$

Is omitting the the parentheses just shorthand that I never realized I was using; $\frac{1}{3} \neq 1 \div 3$, but instead $\frac{1}{3} = (1 \div 3)$?

Should fractions come at the front of (F)PEMDAS/(F)BEDMAS?

Or is it just that the definition of a fraction entails that it is an individual unit and expressing      $\frac{1}{3}$ as $(1 \div 3)$ doesn't really make sense either?

Comment: Yes you could say that a fraction has invisible parantheses. This is a definition yes, but it's logical. I see a fraction as one object and not an operation between two objects.

Comment: Avoid using the notation $\div$.

Comment: You could take $\frac13$ as a single number like $0.5.$ A trickier question would be how to evaluate $3 \div \frac{3-2}{5-2}.$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is this just to get around confusion with the modulo operator?

Comment: @JRN: There is less room for ambiguity if, for instance, you write $$\frac{3}{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} \, .$$You don't have to avoid the divide sign entirely, but note than in higher-level mathematics, it is seldom used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mnemonics BEDMAS and PEMDAS have some utility, but they're not perfect.
They work relatively well for parsing computer code,
where the operands and operators are all written in one linear string.
Even then, neither mnemonic literally describes the correct order of application of operations in all cases.
Just look at the ambiguity between DM in one mnemonic and MD in the other.

As soon as we start arranging things in two dimensions we have the effect of implicit parentheses. There should be no doubt that $\frac 2{3-1}$ is meant to be evaluated like $2/(3-1)$ and not like $2/3-1.$
When we write $e^{2x}$ it means the multiplication $2x$ is performed before the exponentiation, regardless of the occurrence of E before M in the mnemonics.

The mnemonic really should be something like PE(MD)(AS), and I would say it only applies when we have no two-dimensional clues to say what operation applies first, such as in the expression
$3 - 1 \times 3$ (which is $3 - (1\times 3),$ not $(3-1)\times 3)$)
or in the expression $3x^2$ (which is $3\times(x^2),$ not $(3 \times x)^2$).

The two-dimensional clues I would take from a horizontal fraction bar would be that it always has implicit parentheses like this:
$$ \left(\frac{( \cdots )}{( \cdots )} \right).$$

Even these implicit parentheses can be unclear in some cases, so we simply should not write expressions like
$$ \frac{1}{\frac AB}, $$
which require carefully looking at the relative sizes of typefaces and slightly different lengths of horizontal lines.

Comment: (+1): In addition to the problems you have cited about the BIDMAS/PEMDAS mnenomic, it seems to me that it also acts as a barrier to understanding the properties of the arithmetic operations. For instance, it suggests that $a(b+c)$ *has* to be evaluated by adding $b$ and $c$ together, and then multiplying by $a$. Of course, you and I know that multiplication is *distributive*, and so $a(b+c) = ab+ac$. The order of operations should be regarded as something to fall back on in the case of ambiguity, rather than a strict set of rules about how to evaluated expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\frac13=1\div3$, we can write $3\div\frac13$ as $3\div(1\div3)$. But this is *not* the same thing as $(3\div1)\div3$, since division is not associative. In other words, you don't get the same thing if you compute first $b\div c$ and then you compute $a\div(b\div c)$ and if you compute first $a\div b$ and then you compute $(a\div b)\div c$.

It's just like subtraction:$$12-(5-2)=12-3=9,$$but$$(12-5)-2=7-2=5.$$

Comment: Given the level of the question, it might be helpful to explain what 'associative' means, and possibly give an example.

Comment: @Joe It's done.

Comment: The question was about why the parentheses are there when you expand, not why $3 \div (1 \div 3) \neq  3 \div 1 \div 3$. It's just something we all seem to intuitively know. I've always considered fractions to be an alternate representation of division and found this slight difference interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly say that there are implicit parentheses, since $3 \div \frac{1}{3}$ equals $3 \div (1 \div 3)$, not $(3 \div 1) \div 3$. It helps to think of $\frac{1}{3}$ as a number in its own right, an individual unit as you have suggested. It can be visualised as the proportion of the circle below that has been shaded:

[image: One-third]

When you divide $3$ by $\frac{1}{3}$, you are asking 'what number, when multiplied by $\frac{1}{3}$ gives you $3$?'
$$
\frac{1}{3} \times \, ? \, = 3
$$
Here, the $?$ must be equal to $9$, since
$$
\frac{1}{3} \times 9 = 3 \, .
$$
and so $3 \div \frac{1}{3}=9$. The number $3$ can be visualised as shading in $3$ circles. Then, you are trying to think of how many sectors of area $\frac{1}{3}$ can be fit into $3$. If we count them up, we get $9$. Alternatively, note that $\frac{1}{3} \times 3 = 1$, and $1 \times 3 = 3$. Hence,
$$
\left(\frac{1}{3} \times 3\right) \times 3 = 3 \, .
$$
With multiplication, we are allowed to regroup the brackets*:
$$
\frac{1}{3} \times \left(3 \times 3 \right) = 3 \, ,
$$
and so
$$
\frac{1}{3} \times 9 = 3 \, .
$$

---

*The technical term for an operation where you are allowed to regroup the brackets is *associative*, as outlined in José Carlos Santos' answer. For instance, addition is associative:
$$
(3+2)+7 = 3+(2+7) \, .
$$
In general,
$$
(a+b) + c = a+(b+c) \, .
$$
Multiplication is also associative. Be careful, though: division and subtraction are not associative.