Solve the equation 4÷5÷6.
Solve the equation 4÷5÷6.
I'm having issue solving this equation. should we consider (4÷5)÷6 or 4÷(5÷6)?

This is not an equation. And it is certainly a duplicate.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033243

Also, the expression is ambigious.
